# Questions on Depth First Search and Spanning forest

Tags: graph, depth-first-search

Okay so I have this question which I assume that I have a directed path graph which is 1 -> 2 -> 3 -> 4. I know that after I perform a Depth First Search on it will it still be a spanning forest if I take 4 as a source node? and also after I perform Depth First Search with 4 as a source node will it be 1 2 3 4 without any arc or just vertex 4 without any vertex?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your question. If your directed graph is `1->2->3->4`, then running a DFS from 4 doesn't go anywhere beyond the source since 4 has no neighbors. Since the graph is connected, there's only one tree in the forest (it happens to be a linked list, which is a type of tree, but that seems to be accidental), but if your definition of "spanning forest" means visiting all the nodes, then no, you won't get anywhere from 4. Can you clarify what you're asking a bit further, perhaps by defining your terms? Thanks.

Comment: So I am asking if I have a directed path-graph 1 → 2 → 3 → 4 with 4 vertices. Is
it possible to run DFS on it? And by using some chosen order on the vertices, is it possible such that the resulting directed spanning forest has no arc at all?